# Coded UI Tests in Visual Studio 2017 stop working after the software I am testing updates. Does this happen to others?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have gone through and made multiple coded UI tests for a web application written in C#. These tests that I created were specifically for regression testing. I would test the UI of this application to make sure that previously working aspects were still working after new updates rolled out.

Now the problem that I am running into is the CUIT completely do not work after each update. The newer updates do not touch any of preexisting features that I am testing, yet the CUIT do not run at all. It will sit there, load for a minute, and then tell me the tests have failed.

Now, if I go through and recreate some of these CUIT on the new update and run them, they work fine. However, to make all of the tests that I need, it would take hours and hours every single day of updates and completely negate the purpose of making the automated tests.

So I was wondering if this is a common occurrence that other people know how to deal with. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the error logs that you get when executing coded UI test?

Comment: @PankajDevrani This was a couple weeks ago, so I have since moved on from the CUIT in the post. I am still having the same issue though. The error logs from the tests were just saying that the elements I was trying to test could not be found. After further inspection of the code, it seemed that after the updates the positions of the elements would be at different coordinates than before the updates, even though none of the UI was changed in the update.